# cv2 - not all contours detected

Tags: python, opencv, contour

cv2 is not finding all of the contours in my image.

My image is a page from a textbook that I own. It contains 4 flashcard-like segments which all touch one another which I would like to extract into individual images.

Original image:
[image]

After processing:
[image]

And here is it with the largest detected contours drawn on:

[image]

As you can see the 4 "flashcards" are not detected individually, while the whole set of them is as well as some subsections.

I believe the issue may be that the four "flashcards" all touch each other, and so are being considered part of the large contour and not evaluated on their own. Unfortunately the lines connecting the flashcards are thicker than the outer lines, so I cannot just erode until the connecting lines are gone as then the outer lines will also be gone.

What can be done to detect these flashcards individually?

Code if it is useful:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def process(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.pyrDown(gray)
    kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8)
    erosion = cv2.erode(blurred, kernel, iterations=3)
    dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel, iterations=3)
    ret, thresholded = cv2.threshold(dilation, 245, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    return thresholded

img = cv2.imread('test.png')
processed = process(img)
cv2.imshow('processed', processed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(processed, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

c = processed.copy()
c = cv2.cvtColor(c, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
for contour in contours[:8]:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(c, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow('img', c)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please post the original image.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I went ahead and added it, hopefully that is fine.